# Remote Access Windows IoT core device over the internet

Tags: windows, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I am working with Windows IoT core on a Gateway to Run some Edge services, all the ways to connect to the IoT core device is locally, so basically you have to be on the same network, Any possible way to access the device via the internet?

Answer (score 0):

It is a generic network question. There are a two options, depending if this is for private or commercial grade use.

- Configure 'port forwarding' on your router.
- Using cloud service which have a published IP address. Your device 'publish' on a known location and your clients access a known place. For example, you can use [Microsoft Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/). The purpose of remote connection is nothing more than managing the device. You can use [Azure IoT Device Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/azureiotdm).

Comment: Hi, for port forwarding  I have tried but unable to get the proper port number for remote desktop, if you have done any work on the same, can you please share that, that will be extremely helpful.

Comment: From build 16299, the Windows IoT Remote client does not work for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Hi, I am not using a raspberry pi,  I am using Aeeon Industrial Gateways .

Comment: Have you considered to use cloud service to remote manager, such as Azure IoT Device Management(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/azureiotdm)?